# Memoization and strings

Tags: python, string, dictionary, recursion, memoization

I have two strings `X1` and `X2`
and a `lambda_` parameter and I want to compute a function by recursion on the size of the two strings with my following code :

```
def Bk_function(X1,X2,lambda_,k):
    #lambda=0.01
    #k=5
    if k==0:
        return 1
    if min(len(X1),len(X2))<k:
        return 0
    else:
        return (lambda_*Bk_function(X1[:-1],X2,lambda_,k) + lambda_*Bk_function(X1,X2[:-1],lambda_,k)
                + lambda_**2*(-Bk_function(X1[:-1],X2[:-1],lambda_,k) + (X1==X2)*Bk_function(X1[:-1],X2[:-1],lambda_,k-1)))
```

Nevertheless, as the computation time is too important, I plan to go through a memoization step with the following code :

```
def Bk_function(X1,X2,lambda_,k):
    if not (bool(memo.get(k))):
        if k==0:
            memo[k] = 1
        if min(len(X1),len(X2))<k:
            memo[k] = 0
        else:
            memo[k] = (lambda_*Bk_function(X1[:-1],X2,lambda_,k) + lambda_*Bk_function(X1,X2[:-1],lambda_,k)
                    + lambda_**2*(-Bk_function(X1[:-1],X2[:-1],lambda_,k) + (X1==X2)*Bk_function(X1[:-1],X2[:-1],lambda_,k-1)))
    return memo[k]
```

i.e. we keep in memory the values already calculated in an associative array/dictionary. But I do not know if I should define the `memo` dictionary as a global variable, or pass it as an argument to the function `Bk_function(X1,X2,lambda_,k, memo={})` or write `memo={}` at the beginning of the program. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can define the function as you mentioned in the question.

```
def Bk_function(X1,X2,lambda_,k, memo={})
```

But you don't need to pass it as argument when you call the function as the same dictionary from function definition will be used. Just to demonstrate try running the below sample code.

```
def test(k, v, data={}):
    data[k] = v
    print(data)
    return v


test('first', 1)
test('second', 2)
test('third', 1)
```